# WCAG dynamic value issue occurring?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am not able to get value if I use `aria-describedby="${itemText.itemName}"`

```
<span aria-describedby="" class="itemText">${itemText.itemName}</span>
```

Comment: Which JavaScript framework(s) do you use?

Comment: using jquery @LayZee

Comment: Which framework is supposed to populate `${itemText.itemName}` then?